# Test creation of a custom user using DRF

Tags: python, django, authentication, testing, django-rest-framework

The goal is to test creating a new custom user using [APITestCase](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#api-test-cases).

In models.py got two new classes inheriting from [AbstractBaseUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser) and [BaseUserManager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.BaseUserManager), respectively

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    objects = MyUserManager()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user_entity'

    user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    #username = models.CharField(max_length=USERNAME_MAX_LENGTH, unique=True, validators=[validators.validate_username])
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', max_length=100, unique=True)
    last_access = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    last_update = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    user_type = models.IntegerField()
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'user_type']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user_id) + " (%s)" % str(self.email)

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.user_type == 0

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

and

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_generic_user(self, email, username, password, first_name, last_name, user_type):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("Username cannot be empty")
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Email cannot be empty")
        if not first_name:
            raise ValueError("First name cannot be empty")
        if not last_name:
            raise ValueError("Last name cannot be empty")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("Password cannot be empty")

        user = self.model(
            username=username,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            user_type=user_type,
            is_staff=user_type == 0,
            is_active=False
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(user=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, username, password, first_name, last_name):
        return self._create_generic_user(email, username, password, first_name, last_name, 2)

    def create_admin(self, email, username, password, first_name, last_name):
        return self._create_generic_user(email, username, password, first_name, last_name, 0)
```

Then, in serializers.py created a MyUserSerializer for DRF inheriting from a [ModelSerializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer)

```
class MyUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(
            required=True, # make sure email is provided
            validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=MyUser.objects.all())] # make sure email is unique
            )
    username = serializers.CharField(
            required=True,
            validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=MyUser.objects.all())],
            min_length=5,
            max_length=20
            )
    password = serializers.CharField(
            write_only=True,
            required=True,
            max_length=256
            )
    first_name = serializers.CharField(
            required=True,
            max_length=25
            )
    last_name = serializers.CharField(
            required=True,
            max_length=25
            )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = MyUser.objects.create_user(validated_data['email'], validated_data['username'], validated_data['password'],
        validated_data['first_name'], validated_data['last_name'])
        return user


    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('user_id', 'email', 'username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name')
```

a view with APIView

```
class MyUserCreate(APIView):
    """ 
    Creates the user. 
    """

    def post(self, request, format='json'):
        serializer = MyUserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            if user:
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

and urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'api/users^$', views.MyUserCreate.as_view(), name='user-create'),
]
```

From this, then went on to create a simple test of creating users

```
class MyUserTest(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Create a user
        self.test_user = MyUser.objects.create_user('tiagomartinsperes@gmail.com', 'tiagoperes', 'EWFdfew45te!sadf32', 'Tiago', 'Peres')

        # URL for creating user
        self.create_url = reverse('user-create')

    def test_create_user(self):
        """
        Ensure we can create a new user and a valid token is created with it.
        """
        data = {
            'email': 'cnf32344@zzrgg.com',
            'username': 'andresantos',
            'password': 'test',
            'first_name': 'André',
            'last_name': 'Santos'
        }

        response = self.client.post(self.create_url , data, format='json')

        # Make sure we have two users in the database
        self.assertEqual(MyUser.objects.count(), 2)
        # Return 201
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        # Return the username and email upon successful creation
        self.assertEqual(response.data['email'], data['email'])
        self.assertEqual(response.data['username'], data['username'])
        self.assertFalse('password' in response.data)
        self.assertEqual(response.data['first_name'], data['first_name'])
        self.assertEqual(response.data['last_name'], data['last_name'])
```

Thing is, running

```
python manage.py test
```

gets the following error:

> Creating test database for alias 'default'... System check identified
>   no issues (0 silenced). E
>   ====================================================================== ERROR: test_create_user (user.tests.MyUserTest) Ensure we can create a
>   new user and a valid token is created with it.
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\tiago\Desktop\letsgo\COVID19-be\django_server\user\tests.py",
>   line 10, in setUp
>       self.test_user = MyUser.objects.create_user('tiagomartinsperes@gmail.com',
>   'tiagoperes', 'EWFdfew45te!sadf32', 'Tiago', 'Peres')   File
>   "C:\Users\tiago\Desktop\letsgo\COVID19-be\django_server\user\models.py",
>   line 38, in create_user
>       return self._create_generic_user(email, username, password, first_name, last_name, 2)   File
>   "C:\Users\tiago\Desktop\letsgo\COVID19-be\django_server\user\models.py",
>   line 34, in _create_generic_user
>       user.save(user=self._db)   File "C:\Users\tiago\Desktop\letsgo\unstable\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py",
>   line 66, in save
>       super().save(*args, **kwargs) TypeError: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Ran 1 test in 0.172s
>
> FAILED (errors=1) Destroying test database for alias 'default'...

and no users are being created. What can I do to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is at here

```
user.save(user=self._db)
```

The django Model `save` has the following signature.

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
             update_fields=None):
```

Since you are passing a database as value(`self._db`), I think you are expected  to write

```
user.save(using=self._db)
```